# CMake naming convention for option name to generate project with unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, ctest

Some CMake projects add conditional support for generating projects with unit test support.  The pattern followed in the project's root `CMakeLists.txt` file goes something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

(...)
# add subdirectories, libraries, executables, etc
(...)

option(ENABLE_TESTS "Generate project with unit test support" ON)
if(ENABLE_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

Although this pattern is rather common, I've also noticed that the names picked for the unit tests option is somewhat arbitrary.  Although the option `BUILD_TESTING` was introduced in [cmake v3.15](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/enable_testing.html), that name was far from standard prior to that release.  So far I've noticed projects using the following option names:

- `BUILD_TESTS`
- `BUILD_TESTING`
- `ENABLE_TESTS`
- `RUN_TESTS`
- etc...

With this in mind, does anyone know if there's a standard naming convention to control whether unit tests are added or not to a CMake project?

Comment: The option `BUILD_TESTING` had been existed even before CMake 3.0. It is option for CTest module, not just for unit testing. See e.g. [documentation for CTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/module/CTest.html). And I know no naming convention for other (custom) variables which could control tests availability.

Comment: I'm afraid the option `BUILD_TESTING` is from ctest, not cmake per se.  Although ctest is a nice to have, it's still an external module which a project needs to explicitly import in order to use it.

Comment: `is from ctest, not cmake per se` I do not understand. No, `ctest` is part of `cmake`.

Comment: @KamilCuk ctest is an extension to cmake like many other extensions that are bundled with cmake, such as GoogleTest or AndroidTestUtilities.  It is by no means built-in nor a part of the cmake build system.  For example, you need to explicitly include the ctest module in order to use it, otherwise you don't.  For more info please read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CTest.html

Comment: but ctest is the one maintained by kitware, shipped with cmake as part of cmake. `you need to explicitly include the ctest module` you also need `include(CheckSymbolExists)` to use `check_symbol_exists` and for many other library utlities. It's like `#include` in C. `stdio.h` is part of C, the same way `ctest` is part of `cmake`. I think  `GoogleTest` it's primarily a C++ testing framework, not cmake one. Is googletest used to test other languages tests? Like bash scripts?

Comment: `such as GoogleTest or AndroidTestUtilities` So [googletest intenral_utils.cmake](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake#L285) uses `add_test` and [AndroidTestUtilities](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/AndroidTestUtilities.cmake#L37) also uses `ctest` to run tests. I do not understand - [`ctest` is with us from cmake2](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/ctest.html) and is literally advertised as `Testing driver provided by CMake`. It is by all means a builtin and a part of cmake build system.

Answer (score 1):

> if there's a standard naming convention to control whether unit tests are added or not to a CMake project?

I usually see the pattern like:

```
if (YOUR_LIBRARY_BUILD_TESTING AND BUILD_TESTING)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

That way:

- You enable tests of your library with `-DYOUR_LIBRARY_BUILD_TESTING=1 -DBUILD_TESTING=1`.
- Someone else can enable his library testing with `-DHIS_LIBRARY_BUILD_TESTING=1 -DBUILD_TESTING=1`
- When someone else's library includes your library, he can choose if your libraries tests are going to be build or not and usually he wants to only run hes unit tests, not yours.

  - The alternative is to push/pop `BUILD_TESTING` around `add_subdirectory` like `set(sav ${BUILD_TESTING}) set(BUILD_TESTING 0) add_subdirectory(your_library) set(BUILD_TESTING ${sav})`, which looks ugly. And in case you *want* to test the dependent library (ex. with specific different toolchain the upstream doesn't test with) you have to edit cmake files.
- Package builders, maintainers and distributors of your library will just set `-DBUILD_TESTING=0` to overall disable all possible tests.

[Modern cmake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/testing.html), I believe currently **the** `cmake` tutorial, recommends:

```
if((CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME STREQUAL PROJECT_NAME OR MYPROJECT_BUILD_TESTING) AND BUILD_TESTING)
```

which only just let's you omit setting `MYPROJECT_BUILD_TESTING=1` when testing your own project.

Some short research on kitware projects, I see [VTK_BUILD_TESTING](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L106), [PARAVIEW_BUILD_TESTING](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L167), [VTKm_ENABLE_TESTING](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk-m/-/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L193), [SMTK_ENABLE_TESTING](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmb/smtk/-/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L124), and even [${PROJECT_NAME}_BUILD_TESTING](https://gitlab.kitware.com/iMSTK/iMSTK/-/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L86). Some seem to forcible set `BUILD_TESTING` to `ON` when project specific `*_BUILD_TESTING` is enabled.

> So far I've noticed projects using the following option names

Everyone comes and uses hes own convention, I believe this is the reason cmake was actually adopted that well - it doesn't "force" any specific thing. I believe most developers when writing cmake scripts are not aware of `BUILD_TESTING` variable yet, so they start coming up with their own convention - or maybe `BUILD_TESTING` is the wrong name, as it only means that tests are going to be *build*, not *run*. Anyway, as `BUILD_TESTING` is with cmake from a loooong time, I recommend naming project specific flag as a `*_BUILD_TESTING`.

Comment: `t makes no sense to set it manually` I pointed out that the guys who literally wrote cmake do set it manually in their scrpits. `BUILD_TESTING` is expected to be set by the user when configuring the project. `let alone push and pop` if you have a `add_subdirectory` sub-library that does `add_test` and you do not want these sub-library tests to run when you are testing your project, you may push/pop that `BUILD_TESTING` to disable sub-library tests while keeping the value in your library. That's the idea, used when `*_BUILD_TESTING` library specific variable is not provided.

Comment: `you should pay attention...` sure! Any specific parts? Well, I re-read it, and it talks about sub-projects and not wanting to run sub-project tests, so using library specific `*_BUILD_TESTING` variable is advised to enable/disable project specific tests. It also says: `set a BUILD_TESTING option so users can turn testing on and off` - users can set `BUILD_TESTING` to enable/disable tests.